# Find the y position of each line in an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which contains code samples (like a gist in github) which gets syntax highlighted. I also added a small div absolutely positioned to the top left corner of the code samples which I want to move to different lines.

You can see the div marked as a `>` in the top left corner of the picture provided. I want to be able to move that pointer to a specific line of code.

I tried using `split` on `\n` and measuring the height of the first lines characters, and multiplying that number times the index I want to go to but for some reason that is a little off.

[image]

Here is some code I tried:

```
//The code in a pre.. the {{}} is my template code. 
<pre class="code-view" data-id="{{ file.id }}"><code>{{ file.content }}</code></pre>
//The pointer
<div id="pointer">&gt;</div>
//move the pointer to the top left corner of the code sample
$("#pointer").css("left",$("pre.code-view:visible").first().position().left)
$("#pointer").css("top",$("pre.code-view:visible").first().position().top)

//this logs to 15
var c = 0;
var lineHeight = $("span.hljs-comment:visible").first().height();
    //I have multiple pre's on the screen. Only first one is visible.
var codeTop = $("pre.code-view:visible").first().position().top;
function moveToNextLine(){
    c++
    console.log(c,lineHeight,codeTop)
    $("#pointer").css("top",codeTop + (lineHeight * c));
};
moveToNextLine()
moveToNextLine()
moveToNextLine()
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do instead of what you are currently doing about it. Maybe there's another solution out there for your issue, rather than trying to fix your approach.

Comment: What do you want to use the "`y`" coordinate for? Or do you mean row/line number instead of Y-coordinate? Could you please show us a short excerpt of the HTML fragment you've described?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I was really tired sorry. I rewrote the question let me know if that is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing was splitting the text of the `div` by `\n` line breaks. Then I wrapped each line break in a span with `class="code-line"`. That way I could get the position of each line of code in the `div`.